# How do I get a Let's Encrypt certificate working under Mono?

Tags: c#, https, mono, lets-encrypt

I'm writing a program which implements a REST API via HTTPS. So far I've tested it under Windows, by adding a self-signed certificate to the Trusted Store, and it works fine. Now I'm trying to get it working on a Linux server under Mono, using a real certificate from Let's Encrypt, and none of my attempts have so far been successful.

My first attempt was using a `HttpListener`, and installing the certificate on the server using Mono's `httpcfg` tool. After a lot of trial and error, I managed to convert the PEM certificate to a PVK file which `httpcfg` would accept. However, when I start the server and attempt to connect to it from a browser over HTTPS, the server crashes with `System.IO.IOException: Remote prematurely closed connection` errors, coming from within Mono.

Unable to find an answer as to why, and wishing I didn't have to install the certificate on the machine to get it to work, I switched from `HttpListener` to `SslStream`, and have been trying to get a test program working with that. However I am again stuck at trying to get it to accept the Let's Encrypt certificate in some form. Every attempt I make to call `X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile()` with a certificate file results in a `System.NotSupportedException: The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key` error.

What do I need to do to get a Let's Encrypt certificate working here? There doesn't seem to be any documentation for this. At this point I'd like to get `SslStream` working, so that I don't have to install certificates, but I'll settle for `HttpListener` again if there's a way to get Mono to accept it.

Comment: Why not just host behind nginx? Using raw HttpListener, especially on mono, is not very good idea, unless that's some internal application which will never be used by general public (and even then).

Comment: How is it not a good idea? The application needs to be able to securely respond to API requests, both internal and public. I considered hosting behind nginx, but didn't want the requests to lose that security once it hit the nginx layer.

Comment: You mean you don't like that connection between nginx and your app will be unencrypted, even though they are on the same machine and that connection is not accessible from outside that machine?

Comment: I was hesitant to add an extra layer of dependency and have the security become questionable, but you make a good point. I'll have to look into it more, it may be the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Trust me - it is the way to go. Mono is very buggy (I know that from several years of experience with mono on centos) and HttpListener is not a real web server. Even on windows I won't do that, but on mono it's just asking for real troubles. Host behind nginx with reverse-proxy (you can leave your HttpListener as is) and let it handle complicated stuff like SSL. And by the way if you can - use .NET Core instead of mono (still hosting behind nginx though).

Comment: I didn't even know .Net Core existed. I've got my homework cut out for me. Thanks again!